# Single selection to button like radio button

Tags: ios, uibutton, uiimage

i created 5 button with programmatically and i gave tags to each other, this code block is in the `for` loop.

```
                button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
                button.tag= [[answersID objectAtIndex:m]integerValue];


                button.frame = CGRectMake(760*i, 198, 760, 60);

                UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Grey.png"];
                [button setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

                [button addTarget:self action:@selector(clickButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

After click the button, selected button is changing image itself.

```
- (IBAction)clickButton:(id)sender{
buttonPlusID=[sender tag];

if ([sender isSelected]) {
    [sender setImage:unselected forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    //[sender setSelected:NO];
} else {
    [sender setImage:selected forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [sender setSelected:YES];
}
```

but i want to this. i have 5 buttons which images are grey.png . i clicked a button, button's imaged changed green.png, then i clicked another button, it will change green.png and the green.png will change grey.png. like a radio button. is there any way to do?

Sorry my bad english.Thank you for your interested.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is a very common thing to do. I've created my own class to handle this situation.
This class is called ControlGroup and it's only responsibility is to track all the UIControls you add to it and make one and only one of them selected. The controls (in you case UIButton) doesn't need to know anything about each other and you can have as many controls as you want.  And don't forget to remove the controls when you're done with them because this class will retain it's elements.

Here it is:

The *.h file:

```
// This is a very simple class whose only purpose in life is to manage a group of
// UIControls in a way that only one of them is selected at any one time
@interface ControlGroup : NSObject

-(void)addControl:(UIControl*)control;
-(void)removeControl:(UIControl*)control;
-(UIControl*)currentlySelectedControl;

@end
```

The *.m file:

```
#import "ControlGroup.h"

@interface ControlGroup ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableSet *controls;

@end

@implementation ControlGroup
@synthesize controls = _controls;

-(id)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        _controls = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)addControl:(UIControl*)control {

    if (![self.controls containsObject:control]) {
        [self.controls addObject:control];
        [control addTarget:self action:@selector(controlTouched:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
}

-(void)removeControl:(UIControl *)control {
    if ([self.controls containsObject:control]) {
        [control removeTarget:self action:@selector(controlTouched:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.controls removeObject:control];
    }
}

-(void)controlTouched:(id)sender {
    if ([sender isKindOfClass:[UIControl class]]) {
        UIControl *selectedControl = (UIControl*)sender;
        for (UIControl *control in self.controls) {
            [control setSelected:FALSE];
        }
        [selectedControl setSelected:TRUE];
    }
}

-(UIControl*)currentlySelectedControl {
    UIControl *selectedControl = nil;
    for (UIControl *control in self.controls) {
        if ([control isSelected]) {
            selectedControl = control;
            break;
        }
    }

    return selectedControl;
}

-(NSString*)description {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ControlGroup; no. of elements: %d, elements: %@\n", self.controls.count, self.controls];
}

@end
```

Hope this helps!

**EDIT: How to use this class**

The first thing you have to do is import it where you're going to use it. In your case it would be the class where you create your buttons:

1) Import the class `#import "ControlGroup.h"`

Then you have to declare a property to keep a strong reference to it

2) In your *.h file add the following: `@property (nonatomic, strong) ControlGroup *controlGroup;`

After that, in your init method you have to create the object:

3) Add this inside your init method: `_controlGroup = [[ControlGroup alloc] init];`

Now you have a strong reference to a ControlGroup object that you can use. The next thin you have to do is create your buttons. I believe you already have this step.

4) Create your buttons. When creating and configuring your buttons use `UIButton`'s method `setImage:forState` and set one image for the `UIControlStateNormal` state and another one for the `UIControlStateSelected` state.

Finally, for every button you create you have to add it to the`controlGroup` object that you have.

5) Add each button to the ControlGroup object: `[self.controlGroup addControl:myButton];`

Try those steps and let me know how it goes for you.

Comment: i am really sorry, i am new on ios, so can u help me for integrate it? do u have any example about it? Thanks

Comment: No worries. I'm glad I was able to help. Thanks for accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Keep track of the last button that was selected. Then when a button is tapped, reset the previously selected button before updating the newly tapped button.